# "rake spec" migrates the database every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run any of the rspec tasks via rake, the database seems to be dropped and migrated, but if I run them via script/spec path/to/spec, it doesn't. Is there an option I can set so the rake spec doesn't touch the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be running any migrations, only importing db/schema.rb into your test database. This is the expected behavior so your tests use a fresh copy of the database schema before they run. What is your reasoning for not wanting it to refresh the test database?

Comment: Is there a way to disable that? For whatever reason, the developers on this project decided not to use rails migrations to manage the database, so importing schema.rb isn't a valid option.

Comment: If you have a rspec.rake task, look for a line that contains db:test:prepare and comment it out. That should prevent it from trying to load the schema. Without a schema, how are you planning on building the test database?

Answer (score 1):

For what I do I want it off permanently. So with rspec 2.5.0 and rails 3:

Copy rspec.rake to your apps /lib/tasks folder from:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rspec-rails-2.5.0/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake
```

Add this to the top of the file:

```
  Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
    def remove_task(task_name)
      @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
    end
  end
  def remove_task(task_name) 
    Rake.application.remove_task(task_name) 
  end
  remove_task 'spec'
```

Find and edit this line to force a noop:

```
spec_prereq = :noop #Rails.configuration.generators.options[:rails][:orm] == :active_record ?  "db:test:prepare" : :noop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem also when running rspec from the command line. In my cases I was working with an legacy database that had no migrations, so the tests would fail because migrations could not be run.

The solution was to edit the spec/spec_helper.rb file and delete the following line:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
```

After that the tests ran without failing.